# Regex to convert BBCode link to HTML link

Tags: regex, tinymce-4

I am using TinyMCE 4.4 in which, the content source is either HTML and BBCode. A user can insert link in BBCode view and convert to the HTML.

For example BBCode link: `[url href=http://test.com]test[/url]`, I need regex which will convert to the according HTML link.

Below lines there in the TinyMCE BBCode plugin but it seems to be not working.

```
rep(/\[url=([^\]]+)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/gi, "<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>");
rep(/\[url\](.*?)\[\/url\]/gi, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
```

Ideally, Regex should convert above BBCode link to `<a href="http://test.com">test</a>` but it should handle complex URL(with query string params) as well.

Any thoughts how I can make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your BBCode is wrong. It should be without the `href=` simply `url=`

```
[url=http://test.com]test[/url]
```

Then the regexes should do their job correctly.

The regex: `/[url=([^]]+)](.*?)[\/url]/gi, "<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>"` applies for the case `[url=http://test.com]some plain text[/url]`

The regex `/[url](.*?)[\/url]/gi, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>"` is used for the case `[url]http://test.com[/url]`

See it in [action here](https://regex101.com/r/zE9zT7/1)

Comment: Thanks for clarification. You true. May I know difference between two regex or an examples of both?
Regex1 - rep(/\[url=([^\]]+)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/gi, "<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>");
and
Regex2 - rep(/\[url\](.*?)\[\/url\]/gi, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");

Comment: Updated the answer